Help me to identify SMD diodes marked '1DN'
Help me to identify SMD diodes marked 1DN.


Please post a picture

@DavideAndrea There actually is a picture. You can see the link if you edit the post, but for some reason it doesn't show up.


You can see the link if you edit the post. I tried that. No, I don't see it. I also tried a different browser and an incognito window. I don't see one.


@DavideAndrea I fixed the picture. It should show up now.

Yes, now I see it. Thank you.

Please post dimensions

The markings and package seem to match with a CITC B1DWGL-SN rectifier diode. The package is SOD-123S which seems about right from the picture.

